# JSON update/replace node via LINQ

Tags: c#, json, wpf, linq

I need to take a `JSON` file and update/replace some objects of the `JSON` file.  The problem is when I split the `JSON` into different `JObject` they are always `null`.

background:
I need to parse and update a `JSON` file with multiple objects based on `ObservableCollection` (can assume that class of the ObservableCollection will match perfectly the object in the JSON file).  Here is a sample of the JSON

```
{
"Customers": [
    {
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Jane",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    }
],
"Subs":[
    {
        "SubID": "100",
        "Descript": "Sub 1"
    },
    {
        "SubID": "200",
        "Descript": "Sub 2"
    }
]
}
```

In my WPF application, there will be an `ObservableCollection`  for `Customers` and `Subs`.  So I figured that I could take the entire `JSON`, parse out the object that I need, do the updating, then updates the object to save the changes in the `JSON` like this;

```
JObject mainJson = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("MyJSON.json"));
JObject cust = (JObject)mainJson["Customers"];
myColllection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Customers>>(cust.ToString());
///Do update logic
cust = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myColllection));
File.WriteAllText("MyJSON.json", mainJson.ToString());
```

Problem is that cust is always null.  I cannot figure out what am I am doing wrong.  Also, should I be doing this some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `mainJson["Customers"]` is an array not a JObject.  Change your code as

```
JArray cust = (JArray)mainJson["Customers"];
```